# linux execute shell script which echo something to a file

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork

I have a shell scripts ,which will execute something like below:

file:example.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#some other code
echo "someconfig">config_file
```

I hope the config_file just contain someconfig ,but strange thing happen with config_file,It has a single 'c' in the first line. I found no printf('c') in the parent process who execute the example.sh

My process will call the linux c function to execute the script this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int execute_shell(const char *shell)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int iRet = 0;
    if((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", shell, (char*)0); 
        exit(127);
    }
    else
    {
    while (waitpid(pid, &iRet, 0) < 0) {
        if (errno != EINTR) {
        iRet = -1;
        break;
        }
    }
    }

   if(WIFEXITED(iRet) == 0)
   {
    return -1;
   }

   if(WEXITSTATUS(iRet) != 0)
   {
    return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char shell_cmd[1024]="./example.sh";
    if( execute_shell(shell_cmd) == -1 )
    {
        // handle error
    }
    /*other code blew,may be will write to stdout*/
    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes the config file looks strange,not what the shell scripts echo.

I use the cmd to analysis the possibility:
strace -f ./fork

```
[pid 12235] open("config_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 12235] fcntl(1, F_GETFD)           = 0
[pid 12235] fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)       = 10
[pid 12235] fcntl(1, F_GETFD)           = 0
[pid 12235] fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid 12235] dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
[pid 12235] close(3)                    = 0
[pid 12235] fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 12235] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbabb409000
[pid 12235] write(1, "someconfig\n", 11) = 11
[pid 12235] dup2(10, 1)                 = 1
[pid 12235] fcntl(10, F_GETFD)          = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
[pid 12235] close(10)                   = 0
[pid 12235] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
[pid 12235] read(255, "", 52)           = 0
[pid 12235] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 12235] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 12235
```

I do not understand what the meaning of function = num? 
I will appreciate if someone analysis what the meaning of the strace output.

I suspect the parent and child write to the stdout,leading to strange output in config.

In my project we just use the linux c code execute a shell scripts which would echo someconfig to config_file,It run 6 months normally,but one day the config looks strange(two machine,with the same error,first line with c not what it echo to).

I just want to talk if there any possibility this happen,to have a direction to fix the problem.

After analysis the strace output ,child process execute some fd operation,wich make sure child and parent echo to differnet fd.So I think there is no possibility to make the config mess.

Comment: Check out the `man` tool to get more information about tools like `strace`: `man strace`. It says "Each line in the trace contains the system call name, followed by its arguments in parentheses and its return value." and gives an example

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with the minimal code in the question or only if you add something in place of `#some other code` or `/*other code blew,may be will write to stdout*/`?

Comment: If `execlp` succeeds, it never returns, so your `else { _exit(0); }` is superfluous.

Comment: the function: `waitpid()` needs the following statements:  `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>`  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same output

Comment: since all of the `exec*()` functions do not return unless they failed to start the new process, this line: `if (execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", shell, (char*)0) < 0)`  is not valid,  Suggest: `execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", shell, NULL);`

Comment: @user3629249 It doesn't return if it succeeds. The `if` is superfluous but not invalid

Comment: @Bodo I found  no way for me to reproduce the problem,actually I just suspect this point.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks ,I will read the man manual about strace.Your explain seems enough for me.I will read man fcntl also.

Comment: @David C. Rankin  thanks for your advice,I modfiy my example code.

Comment: @J.Doe, sure, the code didn't hurt, it could just never be reached. With any of the `exec..` functions, the current process is replaced by the command, if it succeeds, and control is never returned. On error, you have correctly used `_exit()` instead of `exit()` which avoids Undefined Behavior in case any `atexit` functions are set, which would not be invalid for the forked process.

Comment: Please be more specific about "Sometimes the config file looks strange, not what the shell scripts echo." What output is should be, and what output it actually be.

Comment: @paul thanks for your advice,I modfiy the question,since it is so strange.It appear twice in the last six month.

Comment: @David C. Rankin thanks for mention that.After you comment,I look for the diffence between exit and _exit,if child process fail,alwsays use _exit,thanks a lot.

Comment: That strace output shows the entire string `someconfig` (and a trailing newline) successfully written to the file; it does not demonstrate any problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes,you are right，I just want to analysis any possibility parent and child process write to the same fd(stdout),which make the config_file look strange.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy analysis the strace output,I see dup2(3, 1)  = 1,then write(1),so I think parent will not write to the config_file,but it happens.

Comment: @J.Doe, the return value of that particular syscall is a file descriptor number, not an error (it'll be `-1` on error, and `errno` is set out-of-band). Why do you think anything is failing?

Comment: @J.Doe, ...`something >whatever` redirects stdout to `whatever` for the duration of `something`; it's all working-as-designed. If you had more commands later in the script, it would be doing another `dup2()` to restore a backup of the original stdout. As it is, though, it exits, and takes the modified file descriptor table with it.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly handles any failures seen in the sub function
4. properly calls the function: `execlp()`

Here is what I fixed:

1. the call (and results) of execlp()
2. the handling of the call to fork() when it fails
3. the call to `waitpid()` when it returns an error.
4. added include statements for: `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/wait.h>` for the function: `waitpid()`
5. replaced any calls to `_exit()` with `exit()` since most beginning programmers have no idea about the result of using `_exit()` rather than `exit()`
6. added place to handle the returned value from the call to: `execute_shell()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int execute_shell(const char *shell)
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if( pid < 0 )
    {
        perror( "fork failed" );
        return -1;
    }

    else if (pid == 0)
    { // child process
        execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", shell, (char*)0);
        perror( "execlp failed" );
        return -2;
    }

    else
    { // parent process
        int iRet;
        if( waitpid(pid, &iRet, 0) == -1 )
        {
            return -3;
        }

        if (errno != EINTR) 
        {
            return -4;
        }

        if(WIFEXITED(iRet) == 0)
        {
            return -5;
        }

        if(WEXITSTATUS(iRet) != 0)
        {
            return -6;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int main( void )
{
    char shell_cmd[1024]="./example.sh";
    if( execute_shell(shell_cmd) )
    {
        // handle error
    }
    /*other code blew,may be will write to stdout*/
    return 0;
}
```

I created a file: `example.sh` that contained:

```
#!/bin/sh
#some other code
echo "someconfig" > config_file
```

then ran the command:

```
chmod 777 example.sh
```

to make it executable, then ran the program I posted.

The result is nothing displayed on the terminal, however, now there is a new file: `config_file`  that contains:

```
someconfig
```

I ran the code I posted several times and the file `config_file` contents did not change

I.E. no stray character 'c'
s
What have you not told us?

Comment: Could you put that in your answer?

Comment: I have post the shell scripts,it mainly echo config info to config file,thanks for your advice .I modfiy the code follow your advice and other comment blew.If there any problem ,please let me know.

Comment: In my project we just use the linux c code execute a shell scripts which would echo someconfig to config_file,It run 6 months normally,but one day the config looks strange(two machine,with the same error,first line with c),I just want to talk if there any possibility this happen,to have a direction to fix the problem.